# Where is my bonded network config hiding?

Tags: networking, network-bonding

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

About 18 months ago I successfully bonded/teamed my two network adapters together, and I have no recollection of how I did it. I wanted to make some configuration changes to it today, but all the guides say to use `/etc/network/interfaces`, which has no mention of `bond0`. But `bond0` is working no problem, and shows up in all the other correct places mentioned in the guides I find online for doing this, and the configuration persists through reboots no problem.  Where else should I be looking for my configuration to make changes to it?

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

-

```
ifconfig bond0

bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 50:e5:49:ec:04:a3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3474191336  bytes 4420057363170 (4.4 TB)
        RX errors 2  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 2
        TX packets 1982143191  bytes 1495586643074 (1.4 TB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 49 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

-

```
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 1
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: 50:e5:49:ec:04:a3
Active Aggregator Info:
        Aggregator ID: 1
        Number of ports: 2
        Actor Key: 9
        Partner Key: 66
        Partner Mac Address: b4:fb:e4:1a:e2:57
.......
```

**Netplan Update**
Doesn't appear to be netplan that I can tell:

```
/etc/netplan$ ls
01-network-manager-all.yam

/etc/netplan$ cat 01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

**Update 2**

```
ls -al /etc/network/interfaces.d
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 27  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Apr  1 20:14 ..
```

Comment: IIRC Network Manager calls it teaming. Is there any mention of `team` in NM configuration? Anything in netplan configuration?

Comment: Where is the NM configuraiton?  Google says maybe `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`?  There is no interface config in this file.

Comment: Maybe you've configured it by using `netplan`?

Comment: I don't think so.
/etc/netplan$ ls
01-network-manager-all.yaml
peter@wicks-server:/etc/netplan$ cat 01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/network/interfaces.d` and `ls -al /etc/netplan`, and show me a screenshot of the `nm-connection-editor` window.

Comment: @heynnema I see do see the config in `nm-connection-editor`.  This is a headless server, but I guess since this was installed I must have used this over X Forwarding or something.

Comment: @Peter Check out `nmtui`.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

In `terminal`, check out `nm-connection-editor` or `nmtui`. You'll find bond0 there.

Comment: Ok, so I think nm-connection-editor is something I want... except that I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: @Trevor Please ask a new question. Thanks.